# UML diagram explained

Tags: uml

I have following question about diagram below:

1. How many games can team captain play?
2. How many games can team coach play?
3. If "team" object is deleted does "player" gets deleted too?

[image]

Comment: Do you want us to answer your homework assignment?

Comment: It not homework assigment, I'am preparing for examination. And I just want to check answer if I understand it correctly. For example I understand that player and team holds aggregation relationship, so player shouldn't be deleted if team gets deleted, but player without team seems weird. So bottom line I just asking for some help to prepare.

Comment: a player can exist outside of a team. just because someone's not in a team doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Why is your diagram showing objects? I would expect classes. If not wrong it is at least very unusual.

Comment: @GeertBellekens yes I did wonder that myself but I guess the tutor/lecturer/teacher must have asked about specific instances. Odd, I grant you.

Answer (score 2):

1. A caption is a part of one team, while a team plays in 16 games. So the answer is 16.
2. The minimum number of game that a coach plays is 16 (similar reason as above). The maximum number is a bit tricky. If there are 6 teams in the league and the same coach leads them all (which is possible based on the diagram, although it doesn't make sense), the games the coach plays is 16 x 6 / 2 = 48. I divided the figure by 2 because one game involves two teams.
3. Since the relationship between team and player is an aggregation, deleting team won't delete the player. However, if it is a composition instead of aggregation, deleting team deletes all the 16 players in the team.

Comment: Actually the `:coach` does not `play` a `:game`  It's just that a (number) of `:team` (s) is `Led by`  a `:coach`.

Comment: The `:player`(s) are not deleted, only the ':team'.

Answer (score 1):

1. How many games can team captain play?

   As `:captain` is part of a team he can play 6 games.
2. How many games can team coach play?

   None. The `:coach` leads any number of `:team`(s). If you consider that `playing` here's a calculus: Inside a `:League` (why is that upper case?) you have up to 6 `:team`(s) which can play 16 `:game`(s) (Note: there is no constraint that a `:team` plays against itself, which does look like a bug in the model). So you have max 6*16 = 96 game combinations if there is only one `:coach` for all `:team`(s).
3. If "team" object is deleted does "player" gets deleted too?

   No. Only the `:team` will be deleted. The `:player`(s)  are independent (shared aggregation; WIW: the UML specs has not defined a common semantics for this kind of association and it needs to be defined in the domain)